# Why is not possible for linear layout to have style attributes

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have defined a style for Linear layout but the layout is not visible in graphical view of `main.xml`

---

main.xml.

```
<LinearLayout style="VerticalThemeLayoutInputs">
```

---

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="VerticalThemeLayoutInputs">
    <item name="android:background">#6699FF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

---

Edit:

But below code will work fine but I don't want this code

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="#6699FF"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

---

**Interesting Fact**

I used a `scrollview`. Within that I placed many Linear layout. Layouts properties are almost same so I decided to have a style for that. But what is happening know?  the layout is not visible only in graphical-view but it works fine in emulator.

But actually what is happening? I think its due to Scroll view.

Comment: have used it in your code...? if yes.. how..?

Comment: @ntc yes do you need full main.xml?

Comment: I think you need to call setWillNotDraw(false) on the layout to let it draw itself

Comment: Based on your edits, you probably want to set `android:fillViewport="true"` on your ScrollView.

Comment: Also, if these linear layouts are within a scrollview, you should set  `layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think what you want is `style="@style/VerticalThemeLayoutInputs"`.

E.g.

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/VerticalThemeLayoutInputs">
```

Comment: If that didn't work, you'll need to post more of your layout.

Comment: @vnshetty, thanks for updating the question. I plugged your layout and style into a project and it works fine if you do what is in this answer.

Comment: @ Steve Prentice i got some thing amazing here. i used scrollview within that i placed many Linear layout. layouts properties are almost same so i decided to have a style for that. But what is happening know? the layout is not visible only in graphical-view but it works fine in emulator. amazing!!

Answer (score 4):

main.xml in res/layout/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    style="@style/VerticalThemeLayoutInputs"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml in res/values/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="VerticalThemeLayoutInputs">
    <item name="android:background">#6699FF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

onCreate method in activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_top</item>
```

remove this tag and check.. this seems to be an invalid one.. and in main.xml add `style="@style/VerticalThemeLayoutInputs"` just like the above answer given by steve

Comment: don't tell me u did't know that.. thtas how people usually do.. using style is another way when you have multiple views with same property.. and with your own code everything works fine for me..

Comment: sorry my edit was little confusing now i corrected. i want to use the style using style attribute and not directly

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure from that the style.xml located in Value folder NOT in Ar/EN/..
because he called the default in the first "value\style.xml "